# Allow access to different views and routes with cancancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm managing user and admin roles with cancan. I want the user to have access to certain views ("Cursos", "Credenciales", ) but cancan does not allow it. How can I give them access? So, what is happening is that it tries to access the route but goes back to the root as I specified it to do it in the application controller. (Of course it is supposed to access to the controller through that route.)  Thanks for your help!!

#### index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user %>
  <% if can? :new, @user %>
    <% if can? :new, @empleado  %>
      <li><%= link_to "Lista de Empleados", empleados_path %></li>
      <li> <%= link_to "Agregar Empleado", new_empleado_path %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>      
  <li><%= link_to "Cursos", cursovence_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Credenciales", credencialvence_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

#### ability.rb

```
include CanCan::Ability
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new 
  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
    can :display, :all
  end
end
```

#### routes.rb

```
devise_for :users 
root 'empleados#index'
resources :empleados
resources :users
post '/empleados/:id' => 'empleados#display'
get '/cursovence' => 'empleados#indexCursoVence'
get '/credencialvence' => 'empleados#indexCredencialVence'
get '/proxvacas' => 'empleados#indexProxVacas'
```

#### empleados_controller.rb

```
class EmpleadosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # load_and_authorize_resource - It did not work with this validation
  load_resource  #So, I changed it for only this one

  def index
   ....
  end      

  def new
   ....
  end    

end
```

#### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception
   rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
       flash[:error] = "Access denied."
       redirect_to root_url
   end
end
```

Comment: What is happening that you are not expecting? Are you seeing an error in the browser?

Comment: Hi Sean, I'm expecting users (and admin) to have access to those views. But users cannot have access when I leave the line "load_and_authorize_resource" on my "empleados_controller". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cancan you can assign abilities based on symbols not classes (in case you don't have models to base your abilities on) https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers

So in your view check for `can? :index, :cursos` and `can? :index, :credenciales` given that you added `can :read, :all` in your ability

```
<% if can? :index, :cursos %>
  <li><%= link_to "Cursos", cursovence_path %></li>
<% end %>
<% if can? :index, :credenciales %>
  <li><%= link_to "Credenciales", credencialvence_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Bigsolom. I just tried it but It didn't work. However, in the controller I changed the "load_and_authorize_resource" for only "load_resource" and it worked out. Could you explain to me how it works?

Comment: Replacing `load_and_authorize_resource` with `load_resource ` skips the  cancan authorization for that controller unless you are explicitly calling `authorize!` in your actions. You didn't include a controller code in your question may be you can update it so that we can help u better

Comment: Thanks Bigsolom, I kind of understand now. However I'd like to understand what is the difference between "load_resource" and "authorize_resource". What do they mean by "resource"? I also added the empleado_controller and application_controller code.

Comment: the `resource` is usually the model you are trying to protect it "it's controller"  so you have the `Emplado` resource and `emplados_controller` and in your abilities you'll use `Emplado` model for definitions `can :manage, Emplado`. `authorize_resource` restricts access to controller actions unless it is permitted in ability, `load_resouce` loads the resource in case you want to check for certain attributes in your ability `can :edit, Emplado, user_id: user.id` for example, more on that here: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions

Comment: Thank you Bigsolom, this information was very helpful. I appreciate it.